# SIP - Content List Date Sorting

Tags: list, sorting, sitecore, intranet

I have made a custom Content List in my Web parts directory, and i want it to sort the items after date ascending. Is there any way to do this from the admin back-end? I was looking at the sorting field, and thought i could type something like "Ascending" or "Date ASC". But that doesn't quite work.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a dynamic or a static list?

Comment: Web parts are for Sharepoint, are you sure this is Sitecore and not Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement custom sorting, using whichever field you wish.

See this blog for a walkthrough:

http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2009/08/04/sorting-sitecore-items/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i don't have access to creating class files and such, at the place i work. I was hoping you could change sorting without having to "code" it yourself. :(